# Securing conduit to edge of stud

Tags: electrical, wiring, conduit

I’m looking for advice on how to bring this conduit run up to code, 2 issues in particular:

1. Securing the conduit to the end of the stud, which I believe is required within 3’ of the box.  Are nail straps still allowed for this purpose? I found one on Lowes.com but it did not say UL listed.
2. Securing the cable coming out of the conduit at the top (x mark)*. Since the cable is perpendicular to the joist supporting the conduit, I can’t attach the cable there.  It is however supported when it passes through the joist to the left.  Does this count as adequate support, or do I need to use some kind of conduit or pipe hanger?

*I also planning on replacing that cable with flexible conduit, but I believe FMC has the same support requirements.

[image]

Comment: The nail strap in question: https://www.lowes.com/pd/Sigma-Electric-ProConnex-3-4-in-Nail-Strap-Electrical-Metal-Tubing-Compatible-Conduit-Fitting/1092561

Comment: Sigma is a reputable electrical fitting supplier, and their web site says it can be used in place of one hole or two hole straps, but it doesn't mention code, so it may not "secure" enough. The one hole and two hole straps for EMT they make ARE listed as meeting code, so why not use either of those?

Comment: The joist hole counts as "support" but not as "securing" IIRC. I'd just use a NM clamp fitting on the top end of the EMT to both secure the NM and act as a bushing to prevent abrasion of the cable jacket where it exits the EMT.

Comment: @Armand the stud is too narrow for one of the one or two holed straps.

Comment: Maybe this would work: https://www.elliottelectric.com/P/Item/BLI/BB38D/

Comment: I like the NM clamp fitting idea too; didn’t realize that counts as securing.  I’m actually gonna have to replace the romex with THHN (sleeved in flex conduit) there since the local inspector won’t allow romex in conduit.   I think the nm clamp will work to secure that too.

Comment: Just note that there's a slightly different EMT end clamp for flex vs NM, as for flex the clamp has a keyhole-like center opening with flat edges to block the metal armor from sticking through and abrading the wires.

Answer (score 2):

Gave @Armand ‘s idea another shot - narrowly got it to fit with the one hole strap by drilling at an angle

[image]

Comment: That will catch many, many things over the years. Have you considered screwing a 3" section of 2x4 (or even 1x4) to the side of the stud where you want to put the clamp?

Comment: @Ecnerwal it was already bent that way, but yes, that would allow you to place the clamp higher on the pipe where it will be more sheltered.

Comment: If the concern is catching stuff, why not just wrap a piece of pipe strapping or similar around it in a U shape, and fasten the legs to each side of the 2x4?

Answer (score 0):

On the metal post use a pipe saddle and self-drilling screws.

On the joist secure the conduit with another pipe saddle and wood screws or clouts (if it's not already secured there.

Secure the cable with a cable staple,

Comment: it’s a blue painted 2x4 behind the conduit but I can see how it looks like metal.

Comment: Wood screws instead of self drlling then.